# All $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ matrix has determinant in the first $(k+1)-$columns containing a rank-$k$ minor then those columns are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, independence

> Suppose $M$ is a $m\times n$ matrix $(m\geq n)$. Now for any $k$, where $1\leq k\leq n$,  in the first $k$ columns the top left $k\times k$ minor has rank $k$ (denote it by $M_k$).  And  for all $(k+1)\times (k+1)$  minor containing $M_k$ in the first $(k+1)$ columns have determinant 0. Then show that the first $(k+1)$ columns of $M$ are linearly dependent.

Let $M=(a_{i,j})$. Since for all $(k+1)\times (k+1)$  minor containing $M_k$ in the first $(k+1)$ columns have determinant 0 we have for all $k+1\leq i\leq m$ we have $$b_{1,i}\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}\\ a_{2,1}\\ \vdots\\ a_{k,1}\\ a_{i,1}\end{bmatrix}+b_{2,i}
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,2}\\ a_{2,2}\\ \vdots\\ a_{k,2}\\ a_{i,2}\end{bmatrix}+\cdots+b_{k,i}
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,k}\\ a_{2,k}\\ \vdots\\ a_{k,k}\\ a_{i,k}\end{bmatrix}+b_{k+1,i}
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,k+1}\\ a_{2,k+1}\\ \vdots\\ a_{k,k+1}\\ a_{i,k+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
But with this we get a set of $k+1$ coefficients. How can I get coefficients for first $(k+1)$ many $(k+1)\times 1$ columns to show they are linearly dependent

Comment: The second sentence does not make any sense to me: *"And  for all $(k+1)\times (k+1)$  minor containing $M_k$ in the first $(k+1)$ columns have determinant 0."* How is a $k\times k$ matrix supposed to be contained in the first $k+1$ columns? And you already know all minors $M_k$ have rank $k$, so $M_{k+1}$ has rank $k+1$ so $\mathrm{det}\,M_{k+1}\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat A$ be the $m\times (k+1)$ matrix , which contains the first $k+1$ columns of $A$, We need to show that its rank is equal to $k$. We already know that its rank is at least $k$, since it possesses $k$ linearly independent rows, namely the first $k$ rows. In particular, is $a_j$ are the rows of $\hat A$, then
$$
\dim \mathrm{span}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)=k
$$

If its rank was equal to $k+1$, then it's row space $W$, i.e.
$$
W={\mathrm{span}}(a_1,\ldots,a_{m})
$$
the space spanned by its rows, would have dimension $k+1$. This means that at least one of the $a_{k+2},\ldots,a_m$, say $a_\ell$ does not belong to
$\mathrm{span}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$, and hence
$$
a_1,\ldots,a_k,a_\ell,
$$
are linearly independent, and hence the determinant of the corresponding $(k+1)(k+1)$ matrix does not vanish.

Answer (score 0):

For $(k+1) ×(k+1) $ minor $\det(M_{k+1})=0$ and $\textrm{rank}(M_{k+1}) =k+1$

Contradictory!